# Autotest mongodb to verify query is using index, using C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodb and using the c# driver, I have made several queries for different parts of my application. For the different collections, I have created the appropriate indexes to support my queries, or so I hope.

I want to examine the behavior of my queries to verify that the queries are indeed using indexes. For this, my thought is to create auto-tests which can run explain on the queries and then verifying the used strategies.

However, I have a very hard time figuring out how to do this with the C# driver. An example of my queries is like this:

```cs
IMongoCollection<UserData> collection = ...

FilterDefinition<UserData> filter = Builders<UserData>.Filter.In(x => x.Email, emails);
ProjectionDefinition<UserData> projection = Builders<UserData>.Projection
   .Include(x => x.UserId)
   .Include(x => x.Email);

FindOptions<UserData> options = new FindOptions<UserData> { Projection = projection };
IAsyncCursor<UserData> findCursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter, options);
```

From the c# driver documentation, [I found this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCursor_Explain.htm) (`MongoCursor.Explain`), which is kind of what I was hoping for. However, I have no clue how I get a `MongoCursor`. I have also found the class `ExplainOperation` [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Operations_ExplainOperation.htm), but likewise, I can't seem to find any example of how to use it.

What I currently have working is the following:

```cs
FindOptions findOptions = new FindOptions { Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$explain", true) };
BsonDocument document = collection.Find(filter, findOptions).Project(projection).First();
```

However, the `Modifiers` field is deprecated, telling me to "Use individual properties instead.", but I can't seem to find any explain properties anywhere.

So what could/should I do? The reason for doing it as auto-tests, is that I want guard against changes to either the indexes or the queries, without having to manually verify it within the mongo-shell, but is it unreasonable or bad practice to verify the use of indexes using auto-tests? What alternatives are there?

Comment: `MongoCursor.Explain` and `However, the Modifiers field is deprecated` are about legacy API. If you need just to check the query, you can create a MQ itself (like for the shell) and then run it via `database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("<json query>");`